# echo a single line from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I am kind of stuck since I never tried to get something from the database in this way.

**My problem**:

I have a single line of code that goes to a website for example `src = "www.youtube.com"` however that link is stored in a database that has 1 single table called link so i retrieve this link like this

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM youtubevid");
```

I have always used id's but for this table there is no need because it will get updated and i only need that 1 link. My question is how do i echo this?

Help is much appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: If it contains only one line, that your select will return only that one line.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using `PDO` to do that, if that's the case then you need to execute the query and fetch the result, after the line that you have specified i.e after the.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM youtubevid");
```

Here is the complete code:

```
// prepare the query
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT link FROM youtubevid"); 

// execute it
$sql->execute();

// fetch the result
$result = $sql->fetch();

// echo out the column.
echo $result['link'];
```

Comment: That worked just fine, the problem is i always used `WHERE id = :id` so i barely touched `->execute` or `->fetch` at all i will keep this in mind for future works, thanks a lot!